# MFP8 Push and processDebugResources Error

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I installed cordova-plugin-mfp-push and tried cordova build for android, it throws "processDebugResources" error

I uninstalled cordova-plugin-mfp-push and tried the build, its successful.

how to resolve this ? I need to do PUSH NOTIFICATION, the MFPPush mentioned in the code throws error without this plugin

Comment: Please don't make us guess the error and post the actual error you see. Also, the version of the cordova push plugin you added.

Answer (score 0):

Execute "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-push" and "cordova build android". Inside PLATFORM folder, 
Navigate to "\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-mfp-push" path and edit the "APP-build-extras.gradle" file, change the version mentioned to 26.

Again, execute "cordova build android", build is successful